# MySQL double LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

## Into

I have two tables **profile** and **name**, the profile table contains some metadata relating to a user. The name table contains all the possible names the profile could have.

I am trying to create a **MYSQL** query that will give me the profile.age, the given name and family name for all profiles even if that dont have a given name or family name

## Tables

### Profile

```
    +-------+---------+
    | ID    | AGE     | 
    +-------+---------+
    | 0     |  10     |
    | 1     |  20     |
    | 2     |  30     |
    | 3     |  40     |
    +-------+---------+
```

### Name

```
    +------------+--------+--------+
    | PROFILE_ID |  TYPE  |  NAME  | 
    +------------+--------+--------+
    |      0     |   0    | Jo     |
    |      0     |   1    | Blog   |
    |      1     |   0    | Jim    |
    |      2     |   1    | Smith  |
    +------------+--------+--------+

    Type 0 = Given Name
    Type 1 = Family Name
```

## Quert

This is the Query I am currently using.

```
SELECT given.name AS 'given_name', family.name AS 'family_name', profile.age
FROM profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN name given ON profile.id = given.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN name family ON profile.id = family.profile_id
WHERE given.type = 0 
AND profile_id.type = 1 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

## Problem

This is the result I want and expect to get

```
    +------------+-------------+--------+
    | GIVEN_NAME | FAMILY_NAME | ADE    |
    +------------+-------------+--------+
    | Jo         | Blog        | 10     |
    | Jim        | NULL        | 20     |
    | NULL       | Smith       | 30     |
    | NULL       | NULL        | 40     |
    +------------+-------------+--------+
```

However this is what I actually get

```
    +------------+-------------+--------+
    | GIVEN_NAME | FAMILY_NAME | AGE    |
    +------------+-------------+--------+
    | Jo         | Blog        | 10     |
    +------------+-------------+--------+
```

From what I understand **LEFT OUTER JOIN** should return on the NULL value joins. What am I doing wrong? How do I change my Query to return the NULL value joun?

Comment: +1, examplary question formatting!

Comment: I liked also the formating and I `+1`ed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you have a `WHERE` clause on a table that is being `LEFT JOIN`ed on then you will immediately eliminate the `NULL` rows (i.e. where there is no match).  So for starters, you should move the condition of `given.type = 0` to the `ON` clause instead of in the `WHERE` clause.  And I'm going to assume there is an issue with your other condition on the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT given.name AS 'given_name', family.name AS 'family_name', profile.age
FROM profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN name given ON profile.id = given.profile_id AND given.type = 0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN name family ON profile.id = family.profile_id AND family.type = 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helped me understand what was actually going on, I now understand JOINS a little better.

Answer (score 5):

You are filtering `type` to be 0 or 1(in where clause), this will ommit `null`s.

```
SELECT given.name AS 'given_name', family.name AS 'family_name', profile.age
    FROM profile
    LEFT OUTER JOIN name given 
       ON profile.id = given.profile_id and given.type = 0 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN name family 
       ON profile.id = family.profile_id and profile.type = 1 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT N1.id, N1.name,N2.name, A3.age 
FROM name N1, name N2, age A3 
WHERE N1.id=N2.id AND N1.id=A3.id 
  AND N1.type=0   AND N2.type=1
```

`name` refers to name table
`age` refers to profile table

Comment: Ansi joins / cross joins should not be used here, you should use one of the appropriate join types (i.e. `LEFT JOIN`) to get what you need.